# Is the 404 page the same as "well this is embarrasing" page?

Tags: 404-error

I'm not sure if wordpress 3 upgraded itself from displaying 404 pages to having a "well, this is embarrassing" text in pages that aren't there, but I would like to know whether the tutorials that say "fix your 404 pages" would fix my "well this is embarrassing" page as well.

Thanks

EDIT: Let's say it's the latest twenty-eleven theme.

Comment: What **Theme** are you using?

Comment: Let's say it's the latest twenty-eleven

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on your theme.  Most themes includes a `404.php` template to display a "well this is embarrassing" page or an index of previous posts.

For example:

- My consulting site shows an index: http://jumping-duck.com/does-not-exist
- One of my client sites shows a basic "404 not found" error: http://votebode.com/does-not-exist

They're both running the latest version of WordPress (3.3.2 as of this answer).  Both sites define their own 404 behavior through a themed `404.php` template.

Comment: Default Twenty-eleven theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Twenty Eleven, you could open `404.php` - you would see this code in there:
`<h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'This is somewhat embarrassing, isn&rsquo;t it?', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>`

You can modify this 404 page to show and say whatever you want - it will be loaded every time someone tries to go to a URL that WP doesn't think exists.

The long and short is, a 404 page and a 'well, this is embarrassing' page are the exact same thing - a page being served up by the `404.php` template.

Comment: A better route would be to create a custom child theme that inherits Twenty Eleven and implement a custom `404.php` template there. This protects you from potential updates to Twenty Eleven overwriting your changes ...

Comment: This is what happens when I make assumptions - I figured OP has either duplicated the theme and is working from that or using a child theme according to best practices.  Thanks for pointing this out, though - there are going to be changes to Twenty Eleven in 3.4 very soon.